# using JavaScript variable in place of jquery selector

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, sql

instead of `$('#hello').load("mysql.php");` ,where the selector is a html element , is there any way i can use .load() to store the result in a javascript variable 
something like `var res; $('#res').load("mysql.php");`

Comment: `.load()` is just a shorthand for an XHR request that the appends to the DOM. You can use the many methods provided for making such requests. Storing to a variable must consider the async nature of such requests. Start with `$.ajax`, or just use the `XMLHttpRequest` of `fetch()` APIs directly.

Comment: Store what exactly? Not very clear what you are hoping to accomplish. You can access the response in the load complete callback

Comment: No you cannot `.load ` is intended to work with selectors as the doc says `Load data from the server and place the returned HTML into the matched element.`

Comment: @jenilchristo how you can say "no you can't" when it's not clear what OP is trying to accomplish?

Answer (score 0):

You can make use of the callback, and store the response to a variable. However you do have the asynchronous nature of this function to bare in mind, meaning the `res` variable will be undefined until you get the response.

```
var res;
$('#res').load( "mysql.php", function( response, status, xhr ) {
    res = response;
});
```